# Regex: combining two groups

Tags: python, regex, string

Test string:

```
First
Name:
MICKEY
One to
four lines
of cruft go here
Last
Name:
MOUSE
More cruft
goes here
```

I want to return a single group "MICKEY MOUSE"

I have:

```
 (?:First\WName:)\W((.+)\W(?:((.+\W){1,4})(?:Last\WName:\W))(.+))
```

Group 2 returns MICKEY and group 5 returns MOUSE.

I thought that enclosing them in a single group and making the middle cruft and Last name segments non-capturing groups with `?:` would prevent them from appearing.  But Group 1 returns

`MICKEY
One to
four lines
of cruft go here
Last
Name:
MOUSE`

How can I get it to remove the middle stuff from what's returned (or alternately combine groups 2 and group 5 into a single named or numbered group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you could make use of non capturing groups in regex. These are declared with: `(?:)`

After modifying the regex to:

```
(?:First\WName:)\W((.+)\W(?:(?:(?:.+\W){1,4})(?:Last\WName:\W))(.+))
```

you can do the following in python:

```
import re

inp = """
First
Name:
MICKEY
One to
four lines
of cruft go here
Last
Name:
MOUSE
More cruft
goes here
"""
query = r'(?:First\WName:)\W((.+)\W(?:(?:(?:.+\W){1,4})(?:Last\WName:\W))(.+))'
output = ' '.join(re.match(query, inp).groups())
```

Answer (score 1):

With `re.search()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

s = '''
First
Name:
MICKEY
One to
four lines
of cruft go here
Last
Name:
MOUSE
More cruft
goes here'''

result = re.search(r'Name:\n(?P<firstname>\S+)[\s\S]*Name:\n(?P<lastname>\S+)', s).groupdict()
print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'firstname': 'MICKEY', 'lastname': 'MOUSE'}
```

**----------**

Or even simpler with `re.findall()` function:

```
result = re.findall(r'(?<=Name:\n)(\S+)', s)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['MICKEY', 'MOUSE']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and check if all characters are uppercase:

```
import re
s = """
First
Name:
MICKEY
One to
four lines
of cruft go here
Last
Name:
MOUSE
More cruft
goes here
"""
final_data = ' '.join(i for i in s.split('\n') if re.findall('^[A-Z]+$', i))
```

Output:

```
'MICKEY MOUSE'
```

Or, a pure regex solution:

```
new_data = ' '.join(re.findall('(?<=)[A-Z]+(?=\n)', s))
```

Output:

```
'MICKEY MOUSE'
```